# Responsive column width-height size

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

To show some data I use JQuery DataTables but I need to limit the `max-width` for one of my column to 200px so in my `.css` file use this rule:

```
table tbody > tr > td {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

That limit the width of the columns but if the content it's longer that 200px invade the next column and mix with the content of the next column.

**What I need is, if the content is longer tha 200px the cell expand the height and the content continue in the next line.**

So I tried to use the options for `jdatatables`:

```
$('#idTable').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "widht": "200px" },
                null,
                null,
                null,
            ],
        });
```

But that doesn´t change anything

My table tag looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-hover display nowrap" id="idTable" cellspacing="0">
```

Sorry for my bad grammar, if you need more info just ask me.

Comment: `widht` you have a typo error in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work,

```
table tbody > tr > td {
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```